# How can I convert an image to 16bit high color in gimp?

Tags: color, gimp, bit

I would like to convert an image in to [16bit high-color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_color).  I have gimp installed, but am also open to using web tools or even command line tools.

I read a question where someone suggested just using a grey and alpha channel to get 16bit/px, but I'm trying to see an image with a reduced color palette: [https://superuser.com/questions/988681/gimp-save-png-in-16-and-24-bit#:~:text=For%2016%20bit%20you%20need,have%20a%2016%20bit%20image](https://superuser.com/questions/988681/gimp-save-png-in-16-and-24-bit#:%7E:text=For%2016%20bit%20you%20need,have%20a%2016%20bit%20image).

I don't actually need the image to export as a 16bit/px image format, but I do want to see what it would look like.

---

Found a tool:  https://github.com/dbohdan/hicolor.  Still looking for a less involved solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only want to see, no need to get a converted file? Then it's easy.

**History**

High color was a step to better colors in the era when color was a new thing in low cost computers. RGB displays did show quite the same range of colors as today. The problem was that the small amount of memory in computers and slow calculations force low cost systems use quite sparse set of samples of the color range of the display. In 16 bit high color system (2 bytes per pixel) Red and Blue had 32 brightness steps. Green had 64 brightness steps.

**How to**

You can quantize a normal srgb image which has 256 steps for each channel. Do it with curves. Scale max value 255 to 31 for R and B, but to 63 for G. here it's done for blue (sorry for using Krita, but it's the same in all common image editors)

[image]

The image turns to quite yellow due the reduction of blue. Remember to accept the adjustment.

Scale back the maximum from 31 to 255. Here it's for blue again:

[image]

It's well possible that you see nothing worth mentioning. Just that thing justifies the idea of the high color. Complex images can well look acceptable, no matter blue and red has only 32 brightness steps and green has 64. The difference can be seen in gradients. Here's the normal (srgb, 256 steps) gradient from black to max bright red:

[image]

It's quite smooth. Some banding can be seen because the steps have different widths on the screen due the low pixels per inch resolution. The next one has only 32 brightness steps. The stripes are easy to see:

[image]

The curves adjustment dialog showed in my 1st screenshot the level histogram of blue. It was fully occupied. When the quantization was done the histogram became sparse:

[image]

That's because 5 bit quantization can show only every 8th level of the normal 256 level RGB system.

In the common high color system the 16th bit is given to green, because the eye is said to be most sensitive to see the striping for green gradients. There exists also 15 bit versions where also green has 32 steps and the 16th bit in the 2 bytes per a pixel system is used to transparency or some other information.

But as said, the effect is difficult to see in complex images. As a proof check the next image (a news photo):

[image]

The colors are unedited below the white diagonal. Above the diagonal the colors are quantized to high color levels with curves as shown above.

Searching for "high color" seems to give some obscure information, too. The most common obscurity is that the term brings up color images which have very saturated colors. That obscurity can be built in the web search engines i.e. what they imagine the user likes to see.

Another possible cause is using indexed colors in the usual srgb system - how the used srgb range color are selected, when we allow 32 brightness steps for R and B, but 64 brightness steps for G. The result surely looks oversaturated if the limited palette uses only saturated colors.

Finally we can successfully use a wrong display method for image files which use different than normal color coding. I haven't tried this for high color coded files, but now and then I meet a CMYK jpg which looks like it has wrong colors when watched in program which knows only RGB.

I am sure that the original intention of using 16 bit per a pixel was to make possible a little more realistic colors (about 65k different colors) than what earlier 16 or 256 color systems allowed.The only visual difference to our common srgb system is the easy to see banding of gradients.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can only do this in GIMP when exporting as a Windows BMP image (.bmp file). Note that this format is more or less obsolete today. I suppose after doing this, you could open it up again in GIMP then export as an RGB PNG, but the PNG format doesn't support this actual bit depth.

1. Do *File > Export As*
2. Name your file with the file extension .bmp, then hit Export
3. When the Export as BMP dialog opens, click on *Advanced options*, and choose one of the 16bit image formats, and hit export.

In this example I've chosen Red 5bit, Green 6bit, Blue 5bit (total 16bit).

[image]

If you check the file properties, it should show as a 16bit image.

[image]

What does it look like? Little different from a normal 8bit per channel RGB (24bit) image to be honest. There's a bit more banding in gradients perhaps.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- `Colors > Components > Decompose` to RGB mode
- In the extracted image:

  - Use `Colors > Posterize` on each layer, with 32 levels on Red and Blue, and 64 in Green.
  - `Colors > Components > Recompose` to apply this to the original image.

Original image (continuous histogram):

[image]

16-bit High-Color image (quantized histogram):

[image]

#### Edit: even faster method:

Just apply `Color > Posterize` on the original layer after deselecting channels (which locks their value).

- Deselect green and posterize to 32 values
- Reselect green, deselect Red/Blue and posterize to 64 values
- Reselect red-blue for future used

[image]

Also, saved the initial image to 16-bit high-color BMP (R5G6B5), and comparison shows the re-loaded BMP and the channel-quantized image are identical (histogram of difference is all 0's).